# RBG C color generator

Tags: c, colors

I'm starting now a project in C, using Minix  and I'd like to create a RGB() function, where I should give as arguments three numbers between 0 and 255 and it return one color.

```
#define BLACK rgb(0,0,0)
#define BLUE rgb(0,0,255)
#define CYAN rgb(0,255,255)
```

Any ideas how I can do it?

Cheers

Comment: What have you done? Give an example about what do you want?

Comment: Do you know the formula for taking RGB -> the single color?

Comment: what does `return one color` mean? what do you want to return

Comment: I have a set_pixel Function:

 `code`int vg_set_pixel(unsigned long x, unsigned long y, unsigned long color) {

 unsigned int i,j;

 if(x<0 || x >= h_res || y < 0 || y >= v_res)
  return -1;
 else {
  //printf("%x, %d, %d, %d\n", video_mem, y, x, h_res);
  //*(video_mem + (y*h_res + x)*bits_per_pixel/8) = (char)color;
  char* ptr = video_mem + (y*h_res + x)*bits_per_pixel/8;
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < bits_per_pixel/8; c++) {
   *(ptr + bits_per_pixel/8-1-c) = (char) color;
   color = color >> 8;
  }
  return 0;
 }
}

`code`

Comment: I want the rbg function to accept the blue yellow and red color and make it one because if I want to draw a square , I have to call a function named test_square like this:
test_square(25,25,100,BLUE);

25 and 25 are the coordinates, 100 the size but then I need to call the color and I dont want to put it like 0x32 or something.

Comment: "Color" is not a data type of the C language. Whatever library you're using to draw things, you have to use that library's idea of what a color is, and that depends on the library.

Comment: Check my new answer please.

Color should be specified as an hex code. I said that.

Answer (score 1):

Is your colour by any chance a 32 bit unsigned integer of the following form?

```
0x00RRGGBB
```

If so:

```
unsigned long int
rgb (const unsigned char r, const unsigned char g, const unsigned char b)
{
    return (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}
```

should do the trick. If you have BGR rather than RGB, change the shifts around.

`unsigned long` is used above, but `uint32_t` is technically better.

Comment: better make it an `unsigned long`. int is only defined to hold 16 or more bits

Comment: Looks like it should work. The problem is I should pass it as hex code.

Comment: Pass it to what as a hex code? Use `sprintf("%08x", rgb(r, g, b))` or similar to convert to hex as usual.

Answer (score -1):

Check this btw:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzAWb.png

I have no clue how to use this masks it seems to be more friendly

For those who are complaining that I'm unclear, I'll try to specify a little bit. 
Imagine that , the aim, for now is to draw a square and I have this function:

```
int test_square(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, unsigned short size, unsigned long color) {
    vg_init(0x105);
    int i, j;
    for (i = x; i < x+size; i++) {
        for (j = y; j < y+size; j++) {
            vg_set_pixel(i, j, color);
        }
    }
    sleep(5);
    vg_exit();
}
```

and then to simplify a little bit, since soon I'm going to need much more than this to create my own graphics and stuff, I want to call the colors by their name insteam of searching for the palette every damn time. So I want to call the function test_square like this:

```
test_square(25,25,100,BLUE);
```

and not:

```
// test_square(25,25,100,0x32);
```

and for that I defined a load of macros, i e:

```
#define BLACK rgb(0, 0, 0)
#define BLUE rgb(0, 0, 255)
#define CYAN rgb(0, 255, 255)
#define DARK_GRAY rgb(169, 169, 169)
```

which will need a rbg function to convert those `0, 0, 255` to an hex code.

Thanks for the help, I was almost getting it with your help abligh. Much appreciated.

Comment: Youre probably stuck doing it in two parts: the preprocessor macro can convert the three decimal values into a single 32-bit value. But then you'll need actual runtime code like `sprintf` to convert that value to a textual hex code.

Comment: From what I can see at first Google, the function `vg_set_pixel` doesn't take a hex code for color, it takes an unsigned int. Unfortunately, the doc I found has zero info about the format of that int, so you'll have to find some better documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure green as 0x32 is hex code, right? :P

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between a number and the textual representation of a number, you have way bigger problems than looking up an obscure library function. Is there some actual working code you can find that calls this function for us to look at?

Comment: I was just being ironic. Because the code that you've found on google is probably from doxygen or even code developed by students :)
int vg_set_pixel(unsigned long x, unsigned long y, unsigned long color) {

 unsigned int i,j;

 if(x<0 || x >= h_res || y < 0 || y >= v_res)
  return -1;
 else {
  //printf("%x, %d, %d, %d\n", video_mem, y, x, h_res);
  //*(video_mem + (y*h_res + x)*bits_per_pixel/8) = (char)color;
  char* ptr = video_mem + (y*h_res + x)*bits_per_pixel/8;
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < bits_per_pixel/8; c++) {
   *(ptr + bits_per_pixel/8-1-c) = (char) color;
   color = color >> 8;

Comment: That looks like is pushing bytes straight from the int argument into bytes of video memory. That's pretty awful, hardware dependent, endianness dependent, and all that. I don't think I'd want to use this library, whatever it is.

Comment: I'm working on minix, everything about this is pretty awful. I just wanto to make a function that converts the three [0-255] colors to one single "color" represented in 8bits in the 0xXX format.

Comment: Which would be trivial if I could tell what order they're supposed to be in, but I can't from the docs provided so far.

Comment: This might help I thinkhttp://web.fe.up.pt/~pfs/aulas/lcom2014/labs/lab1/lab1.html

Comment: That's about text mode.

Comment: For crying out loud. I just have no idea. I'm printing green as a 0x32 and I can't figure out the damn pallete. 
I really appreciate your patience but this is getting me nuts